# history.pushState and load new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By using history.pushState I can change the browser URL, but I can't seem to load the next page smoothly.

Here's my code,

```
$('#askq').click(function(){
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new");;
    $.get('/new.html')
        .done(function(data){
            $('html').html(data);
        });
     });
```

Although this loads the page contents it appears more like an iframe because the handlebars.js code that used in the parent window gives error messages in the console when the content changes, meaning the 2nd page is not opening independently of the first. How to fix this error and smooth load the next page together with the URL change?

Comment: If you are replacing the *entire* page, what's the point of using Ajax? It's just unnecessarily complicated (meaning more work for you and more places where things can go wrong). Use a plain link.

Comment: @Quentin well plain link will not load the content smoothly like in ajax without reloading the browser window. How to do that?

Comment: What's smoother about dumping all the content in using `.html()`?